# Layout design inside Android onCreate()

Tags: android, android-layout, layout

I need to create few check boxes and a button inside onCreate() method in Android. Once I create as follow they are  appear in  the same line. How to make them in separate lines, within onCreate() method?

```
final CheckBox b1=new CheckBox(this);
b1.setId(1);
b1.setText("First");
b1.setChecked(false);


final CheckBox b2=new CheckBox(this);
b2.setId(2);
b2.setText("Second");
b2.setChecked(false);

Button btn=new Button(this);
btn.setText("Send");


LinearLayout layout1=new LinearLayout(this);
layout1.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
layout1.addView(b1);
layout1.addView(b2);
layout1.addView(btn);
setContentView(layout1);
```

Comment: Why are you not creating layouts using xml ? It is easier than this. I mean you are not achieving anything by creating simple buttons and checboxes in class file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to set Orientation into your Linear Layout:

```
layout1.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your `LinearLayout` initialization as follows:

```
LinearLayout layout1=new LinearLayout(this);
layout1.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
layout1.setOrientation(VERTICAL);
```

We are simply adding line:

```
layout1.setOrientation(VERTICAL);
```

> `setOrientation(orientation)` Pass HORIZONTAL or VERTICAL. Default
>   value is HORIZONTAL.

Answer (score 0):

try below code

```
LinearLayout layout1=new LinearLayout(this);
layout1.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
layout1.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
```

Answer (score 0):

set your layout orientation :

```
layout1.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set your orientation method in the design screen itself by just clicking in the Set Horizontal orientation or Set Vertical Orientation buttons... By creating the layouts using xml is much easier than anything...